# How to remove the option to select what's inside a text widget, (not by using state = disabled)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried using `exportselection = False`

this is the code I use to get the input from the user, if the user is highlighting the text widget (while inputting their answer), they are able to edit where the input get's printed

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    
    window = tk.Tk()
    
    numb_of_times = 5
    
    window.geometry('1920x1080')
    window.configure(bg = 'blue')
    
    input_board = tk.Text(window,state = "disabled")
    input_board.pack()
    input_board.place(x = 100,y = 40)
    
    def send():
     input_board.configure(state="normal")
     input_board.insert(tk.INSERT, '%s\n' % user_input)
     input_board.configure(state="disabled")
    
    
    for i in range(numb_of_times):
     user_input = input()
     print(user_input)
     send()
    
    window.mainloop()
```

I have tried using exportselection = False

Comment: In what way does `state=DISABLED` fail to meet your needs?  Because that's the only way provided to prevent interaction with a Text widget.

Comment: I have to ENABLE it to insert text, and because of that when the user inputs data while highlighting text in a text widget, they can print the location of the text on the highlighted area

Comment: You can enable it just long enough to insert text programatically, then reset it to disabled. It is impossible for the user to enter data in that small period of time. That is, unless you call `update` in that short period of time, which you should never do.

Comment: Just to get some clarification: you want the user to be able to add and delete text interactively (ie: type into the text widget), but don't want them to be able to select any text while they do so. Is that correct?

Comment: I already set it to disabled after the text is inserted, but it seems that if the user inputs WHILE highlighting the text box, they are able to by-pass this

Comment: and yes that's exactly what I want them to do, except for deleting text (just inserting)

Comment: _"I already set it to disabled after the text is inserted, but it seems that if the user inputs WHILE highlighting the text box, they are able to by-pass this"_ - that literally seems impossible since they can't be inserting text while you have code manipulating the text widget. Can you please provide an example of what you tried? Maybe your description doesn't accurately reflect what you're doing.

Comment: ill just add it to the question

Comment: sorry, this is just an example considering I Don't have the original code. (the original does use a text widget)

Comment: yeah, sorry about that (I updated it)

Comment: Ok, I see how it's possible. However, I don't understand why you don't want the user to be able to select text. Do you not want them to be able to copy information? Have you considered simply removing the selection before calling `insert`?

Comment: how do I clear the selection? also no I do not want users being able to copy text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the selection changes in the text widget, it emits a `<<Selection>>` event. You can bind to that event and remove the selection. This should prevent any text from being selected.

The selection is represented by the tag "sel", which you can pass to `tag_remove`.

The solution might look something like this:

```
def remove_selection(event):
    event.widget.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")

input_board.bind("<<Selection>>", remove_selection)
```